# How would I go about setting a CSS gradient background in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css

The CSS gradient is described [here](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/cross-browser-css-gradient), but I have no idea how to select for these properties in JavaScript. I would rather not use jQuery for this if at all possible.

EDIT: Just doing the following doesn't seem to work...

```
document.getElementById("selected-tab").style.background = "#860432";
document.getElementById("selected-tab").style.background = "-moz-linear-gradient(#b8042f, #860432)";
document.getElementById("selected-tab").style.background = "-o-linear-gradient(#b8042f, #860432)";
document.getElementById("selected-tab").style.background = "-webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#b8042f), to(#860432))";
document.getElementById("selected-tab").style.background = "-webkit-linear-gradient(#b8042f, #860432)";
```

Comment: Seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/B6sEr/ (Chrome 19, Firefox 13).

Comment: For a plain JavaScript solution, see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15071347/1306809

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a JS expert, but my guess is that your settings overwrite each other, so you might want to create a css class selector for this like .gradientBackground and check out the link below:

[Change an element's class with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-css-class-with-javascript)

Comment: If you had looked at the page that describes how the gradient works, you would realize that the CSS creates the gradient effect, background, has to be overloaded in order to be cross-browser compatible.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use jQuery how do you want to apply the style? You should be creating a class or ID which contains the gradients for each browser. Then use jQuery to set that class to ID "selected-tab"

```
.someGradient{
    background: #1e5799; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #1e5799 0%, #2989d8 50%, #207cca 51%, #7db9e8 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#1e5799), color-stop(50%,#2989d8), color-stop(51%,#207cca), color-stop(100%,#7db9e8)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #1e5799 0%,#2989d8 50%,#207cca 51%,#7db9e8 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #1e5799 0%,#2989d8 50%,#207cca 51%,#7db9e8 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #1e5799 0%,#2989d8 50%,#207cca 51%,#7db9e8 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(top,  #1e5799 0%,#2989d8 50%,#207cca 51%,#7db9e8 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1e5799', endColorstr='#7db9e8',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
```

jQuery

```
$("#selected-tab").addClass('someGradient');
```

Before

```
 <div id='selected-tab' class='arial'>Hello world</div>
```

After

```
 <div id='selected-tab' class='arial someGradient'>Hello world</div>
```

Comment: It was requested that if possible the answer should not involve jQuery.

Comment: Then use Javascript `document.getElementById("selected-tab").className += " MyClass";`