# Displaying percentage bar with background color ASP.Net RowDataBound

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, stylesheet

I have a Asp.net Gridview where the last column is my total and col 2-x will be my number.

I want to display a bar showing the percent

Using the example found [Displaying percentage bar with background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26800577/displaying-percentage-bar-with-background-color) 
I want to modify it to work onRowDataBound

First I create a method to get the style

```
 private string colPercent(long Total, long count)
    {
        var y = decimal.Parse(Total.ToString()) / count;
        decimal percent =Math.Round(y,2 );

        string _return = $"height:30px; background: -webkit - linear - gradient(left, #efe3af {percent}%,#ffffff {percent}%);";
        _return+= $"background: -moz - linear - gradient(left, #efe3af {percent}%, #ffffff {percent}%);";
        _return += $"background: -ms - linear - gradient(left, #efe3af {percent}%,#ffffff {percent}%)";
        _return += $"background: -o - linear - gradient(left, #efe3af {percent}%,#ffffff {percent}%);";
        _return += $" background: linear - gradient(to right, #efe3af {percent}%,#ffffff {percent}%);";

        return _return;
    }
```

Next on RowDataBind I loop the columns

```
     if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {

      for (int i = colstart; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
     {
     e.Row.Cells[i].Attributes.Add("Style", colPercent(long.Parse(e.Row.Cells   [e.Row.Cells.Count -1 ].Text), long.Parse(e.Row.Cells[i].Text)));

      }
    }
```

Nothing seems to be changing. what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

the answer is to first remove the spacing in the style. VS reformatted it then

```
   e.Row.Cells[i].Attributes.CssStyle.Value = colPercent(long.Parse(e.Row.Cells[e.Row.Cells.Count - 1].Text), long.Parse(e.Row.Cells[i].Text));
```