# JS Color Generator Not Working

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a webpage where JS will generate 2 colors and use them in a gradient. Here is what I have:

### HTML

```
<div id="hi"></div>
```

### CSS

```
div {
width:100px;
height:100px;
}
```

### JS

```
var hue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 360);
var top = "hsl(" + hue + ",100%,30%";
var bottom = "hsl(" + hue + ",100%,50%)";
document.getElementById('hi').style.background = "linear-gradient(" + top + "," + bottom + ")";
```

Demo that doesn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/8pzaeo3w/16/

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )` Learn how to debug JavaScript: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging

Comment: Also note that you are using different code in your jsFiddle.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15071062/using-javascript-to-edit-css-gradient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient):

> Gradients are defined as CSS `<image>` data types; they can be used only where an image data type is required. For this reason, linear-gradient won't work on `background-color` and other properties requesting `<color>`.

However, you can assign it to `background`. The other problem is your `top` value. The value you generate is:

```
hsl(286100%,30%
```

I'm sure you can find out what is wrong with that.

If you fix both things it works. I recommend to [learn how to debug JavaScript](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging) so that you are able to inspect variables yourself.