# Change single color of linear gradient

Tags: javascript, css

How can I change the first color only in CSS linear gradient using Javascript?

```
div {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #F6F6F6, #E9E9E9)
}
```

as you can see I want to change the color "#F6F6F6" only.

the script must be in Javascript not jquery.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15071062/4334348

Comment: no, but I think if I could extract the second color and save it as variable then I can add the new color with the second color in linear-gradient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the class from the div and add a new class with the new attributes.

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/reko91/suuwe4wc/4/

I would add another class that applies to all divs, in this case 'divs' and the linearGradient class too.

```
<div class='divs linearOne'>
</div>
```

Only added JQuery for button click

```js
var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('divs');

var toggle = false; //used to toggle between

document.getElementById('clickme').addEventListener("click", function (event) {
  if(!toggle){ 
      divs[0].classList.remove('linearOne')
      divs[0].classList.add('linearTwo');
      toggle = true;
    } else {
      divs[0].classList.add('linearOne')
      divs[0].classList.remove('linearTwo');
      toggle=false;
      }

})
```

```css
.linearOne {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #F6F6F6, #E9E9E9)
}

.linearTwo {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #000000, #F6F6F6)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='divs linearOne'>

</div>

<button id='clickme'>
Toggle Gradient
</button>
```

Comment: @Haithomy did you read my answer ? I said I only used JQuery for the button click, everything else is pure JS

Comment: @Haithomy edited answer to use javascript even for button click

Answer (score 0):

If your `<div>` has an `id`, using JavaScript to change the background to (1) another gradient, (2) some color, or (3) no background at all is really as simple as this :

```js
document.getElementById('anotherGradient').style.background = "-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #00E9E9, #F6F600)";
document.getElementById('greyBackground').style.background = "#E9E9E9";
document.getElementById('noBackground').style.background = "none";
```

```css
div {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #F6F6F6, #E9E9E9)
}
```

```html
<div id="anotherGradient">
    This DIV should have a different gradient
</div>
<div id="greyBackground">
    This DIV should have a grey background but no gradient
</div>
<div id="noBackground">
    This DIV should not have any background at all
</div>
<div>
    This DIV should have the original gradient
</div>
<div>
    This DIV should have the original gradient
</div>
```

(see also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/jyLh6sxb/5/))