# Add or change a linear gradient to a background image with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, background-image

According to the documentation I have found, implementation for linear gradients on top of background images are bound together in this syntax:
`background-image: url(IMAGE_URL), linear-gradient(#color1, #color2);`
I want to manipulate the linear-gradient OR just add one entirely, with Javascript without changing the url. Is that possible?

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you **do some additional research**, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15071347/4229270

Comment: The link doesn't seem to help. The problem is that my syntax is like this: `style="background:linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.45), rgba(0,0,0,0.50)), url('../sites/default/files/file.jpg')"`. On hover, I want to change the linear-gradient but leave the URL as it is.