# DOM Manipulation and styling the background

Tags: javascript, css

I have a list that I want to give a metal/metallic background for each item in the list using DOM manipulation.

List using Bootstrap 4

```
 <ul id="items" class="list-group">
   <li class="list-group-item">Item 1</li>
   <li class="list-group-item">Item 2</li>
   <li class="list-group-item">Item 3</li>
   <li class="list-group-item">Item 4</li>
 </ul>
```

This is my attempt to style the background of the class.

```
var backGroundMetallic = document.getElementsByClassName("list-group");

for(var i = 0; i < backGroundMetallic.length; i++) {
  backGroundMetallic[i].style.backgroundColor = '#7fffd4';
}
```

I'm only able to put use one CSS color. Is there a way to reference a CSS class so I can use more than one style in order to style the background for the list to achieve making it metal/metallic?

Comment: Try `var backGroundMetallic = document.getElementsByClassName("list-group-item");`

Comment: What does "metal/metallic" mean to you? Show some examples of what you want. Also, why DOM manipulation? CSS is much more efficient.

Comment: are you trying to add a background gradient then check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15071062/using-javascript-to-edit-css-gradient

Comment: You could use a linear gradient effect to make the background look metallic.Try playing around with the Gradient Generator at https://www.cssmatic.com.

Comment: This isn't "DOM Manipulation". Styling has next to nothing to do with the DOM.

Comment: I can't see how is using JavaScript relevant in such case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a CSS class to an element, you can use [`.classList.add()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList):

```js
var backGroundMetallic = document.getElementsByClassName("list-group");

for(var i = 0; i < backGroundMetallic.length; i++){
    backGroundMetallic[i].classList.add("metallic");
}
```

The same functionallity in one line:

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".list-group")
  .forEach(el => el.classList.add("metallic"))
```

And define the class:

```css
.metallic{
  background-color: #7fffd4;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Either put all the styles in a class and do

```
backGroundMetallic[i].classList.add(classname);
```

or do

```
backGroundMetallic[i].setAttribute("style", "color: red; background-color: black;");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code and custom the `linear-gradient` as you want:

```
for(var i = 0; i < backGroundMetallic.length; i++) {
  backGroundMetallic[i].setAttribute('style','background-color : #e7eff9;background-image : linear-gradient(315deg, #e7eff9 0%, #cfd6e6 74%);');
}
```